Movie about two women stealing babies
I remember seeing this movie a long time ago and I have been trying to find it but have had no luck with Internet searches.
I remember that these two women were hiring men to snatch babies because they couldn't have children or something. I do remember that one of the women names was Helen and the two women had a fight on top of a building and Helen fell to her death.
Does this sound familiar to anyone? I think it was a made-for-TV film. I believe it was in the early 2000s. The movie was made earlier, I think such as the 90s or maybe earlier than that. 

How long is 'a long time ago'?  Even a range here would be helpful.

I believe it was the early 2000s. The movie was made earlier I think such as the 90s or maybe earlier than that.

Strongly suspect this is the 1997 TV movie When the Cradle Falls.

A woman is delighted to have given birth to a baby girl but her life is turned into a nightmare when she goes missing. The police mount a frantic search but to the woman's horror she finds out that it's herself who is the main suspect.

Two older women kidnap babies there, with one (Helen, played by Linda Gray) blackmailing the other (Joan, who works at the hospital and is played by Cathy Lee Crosby) to steal them, and it all does end on a roof where I think Joan pushes Helen to her death, but it's hard to verify. It's hard to find clips too, but you can (barely) see the promo here around the 1 minute mark:




That is the movie I was looking for! Thank you walt
